# ASP.NET Core Form Validation does not work

Tags: asp.net-core, .net-core, asp.net-core-mvc

I looked at many articles before writing this question. I am learning ASP.NET Core 8 and the data validation/annotation does not work in my exercise. When I debug the data object that the form's post is sending, the name value is shown to be null yet no error. Please could anyone guide me with their experience.

Below is the code scenario:

Model:

```
 public class Employee
 {
     [Required] public int ID { get; set; }
     [Required(AllowEmptyStrings = false)]
     public string Name { get; set; }
     public decimal Salary { get; set; }
  }
```

Views - Edit view is used for `GET`

```
@model Employee;

<div class="container">
<h1>Edit Form</h1>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-sm-8">
            <form class="d-grid form-control-sm" asp-controller="Employee" asp-action="EditPost" method="post">
                <div class="form-group row">
                    <label class="col-sm-2" asp-for="Name">Name</label>
                    <input type="text" class="col-sm-4" asp-for="Name"/>
                    <span asp-validation-for="Name" style="color:red"></span>
                </div>
                <input class="btn btn-primary col-sm-4" type="submit" name="Submit" value="Submit" />
            </form>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Controller:

`Edit` for `GET`, `EditPost` for `POST`. `EditPost` has no view of its own, it is passing modified data to another action item.

```
        [HttpGet]
        public IActionResult Edit(int id)
        {
            return View(emplist.Find(e => e.ID == id));
        }
        [HttpPost]
        public IActionResult EditPost(Employee emp) 
        {
            int index = emplist.FindIndex(e=>e.ID==emp.ID);
            emplist.RemoveAt(index);
            emplist.Insert(index, emp);
            return View("Detail", emp);
        }
```

Button to submit form:

`<input class="btn btn-primary col-sm-4" type="submit" name="Submit" value="Submit" />`

The `Required` validation on `Name` does not show up.

I use the edit form to edit the values to null/blank. Here you see first, the name populates as it should:

[image]

Now I blank the input box and submit the form

[image]

The blank name is accepted:

[image]

Comment: Added: Learning ASP.NET Core 8 MVC

Comment: Please add code and data as text [(using code formatting)](https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help#duplicate=0), not images. Images: A) don't allow us to copy-&-paste the code/errors/data for testing; B) don't permit searching based on the code/error/data contents; C) are difficult to read clearly by visual impaired user and other reasons explained in detail here. [Why should I not upload images of code/data/errors when asking a question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-should-i-not-upload-images-of-code-data-errors-when-asking-a-question)

Comment: @Steve Thank you for the advice. I have changed it.

Answer (score 0):

You could validate the ModelState for errors in the `EditPost` action method

```
[HttpPost]
public IActionResult EditPost(Employee emp) 
{
     if (!ModelState.IsValid)
     {
          return View("Edit", emp); // Returns the model back to Edit view with validation errors
     }

     int index = emplist.FindIndex(e=>e.ID==emp.ID);
     emplist.RemoveAt(index);
     emplist.Insert(index, emp);
     return View("Detail", emp);
}
```

Also make sure you add the line `@addTagHelper *, Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.TagHelpers` in your `_ViewImports.cshtml` file.

Comment: For more information and scenarios, go through the Microsoft documentation [Model validation in ASP.NET Core MVC and Razor Pages](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/models/validation?view=aspnetcore-8.0)

Answer (score 0):

```
Step-1
create partial view name of   _ValidationScriptsPartial.cshtml

<script src="~/lib/jquery-validation/dist/jquery.validate.min.js"></script>
<script src="~/lib/jquery-validation-unobtrusive/jquery.validate.unobtrusive.min.js"></script>

step-2
Add spanTag and  partialview according below in View

<div class="form-floating py-2 col-12">
    <input asp-for="Name" class="form-control border-0 shadow" />
    <label asp-for="Name" class="ms-2"></label>
    <span asp-validation-for="Name" class="text-danger"></span>
</div>
@section Scripts{
    @{
    <partial name="_ValidationScriptsPartial"/>
    }
}
```